# Will addAll function in Java make a copy

Tags: java, list, copy

When `list.addAll(list2)` is called will objects in lists be copied to list? or just copy their references... did not find any explanation on javadoc...

Answer (score 41, accepted):

No copy of the objects or their data are made; their references are simply added to the list object.

Comment: So what will happen if we add an element later to the `list2` ? Will it be added to `list` automatically?

Comment: Means if I modified an element in `list2`, then I'll see the modification from output `list` right?

Comment: how would you make a copy and addAll?

Comment: @Jacolack just use 'List<YourObject> secondList = new ArrayList<>(firstList);' This would create new Objects in the new List but with the values of the old values.

Comment: @Snickbrack Nope. As all the existing answers make very clear, the new list will contain references to the original objects, *not* new objects.

Answer (score 5):

No, the objects will not be copied; references to the same objects will be added to the list.

Comment: But does the contract enforce this? I see that ArrayList implements addAll() with a shallow copy, but there is no specification in the doc.

Comment: @ZiyaoWei It states that it "appends all the elements", so that's what it will do--append all the elements. A copy of an element isn't the element, it's a copy.

Comment: @ZiyaoWei: there's no general way to copy an object in Java: there are no automatically generated copy constructors as in C++, and the `clone()` method is supported by very few classes. Therefore, a container that *wanted* to copy all its elements would find itself unable to do so.

Comment: So what will happen if we add an element later to the `list2` ? Will it be added to `list` automatically?

Comment: how would you make a copy and addAll?

Comment: @DaveNewton No, its not a copy. Its a reference to the same object. If you change the object in the List it would also change "outside" of the list.

Comment: @Snickbrack Yes, and that’s the point of the comment, clarifying the OP’s question on this answer. A decade ago.

Comment: @DaveNewton yeah I know I am able to read. But your answer for the copy is misleading and thats why I clarified that `addAll` doesn't create any copies but uses references. And I dont care if its decades if it is still wrong.

Comment: @Snickbrack It isn’t. It specifically addresses the OP’s question regarding whether or not it’s enforced—a copy would not follow the documentation, because the docs state it “appends the element”, and a copy of an element isn’t the element  I don’t know how to make it any clearer for you.

Comment: @DaveNewton You already said it by yourself. ` it “appends the element”`. The element itself. But Java doesn't work with the element itself but a reference. so its not a copy it is a reference to exactly this element. So there are no copies at all. Just references. A copy would mean that if I change an element of this list nothing would happen to the original. But if you change an element in a list which is also in another list then both getting changed.

Comment: @Snickbrack Correct, which is what I said. The point is **explicitly** that a copy of an element isn't the element, therefore when it says "appends all the elements" it cannot be a copy of the element, thus the OP's question regarding "does the contract enforce this" says it's not a copy--everybody here, including me, has been saying it's not a copy for 10 years.

Answer (score 3):

In general, java will not copy objects when you "add all", that is, for objects, pointers to the originals are used.

***** But be careful ! For strings, due to immutability, an array copy will not point to the original string values, and you must not expect that changing a pointer to a string that was added to an array list will result in a new value inside the array list.

Comment: how would you make a copy and addAll?

Comment: @Jacolack just use 'List<YourObject> secondList = new ArrayList<>(firstList);' This would create new Objects in the new List but with the values of the old values.

Comment: @Snickbrack Nope. As all the existing answers make very clear, the new list will contain references to the original objects, *not* new objects.